# Declaring arrays in C

Tags: arrays

Yesterday I was helping a friend w/ some C progamming and he used to declare arrays in this way:

```
/*includes*/
int i; 
scanf("%d",&i);
int array[i];
```

I don't think it's a legit way but the compilers gave no error... So is it right/possible to declare an array or there could be any problem with that kind of declaration?

Comment: This is variable length array or VLA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in ([How do compilers treat variable length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627235/how-do-compilers-treat-variable-length-arrays)) in the C99 version of the C standard, variable length arrays are permitted. However, they are not permitted in any version of C++.

Comment: Ok that's why i got confused: i l'am studying c++ right now and when I studied C I never saw that kind of declaration since I was used to use dynamic lists of elements... Ty for the answer